# Optimizing NOT IN and a subquery?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this query:

```
select distinct somecolumn from sometable
          where something = somethingelse and
          someid not in (select anotherid from another tabele where ...);
```

I think the query runs really slow because of the subselect. Is there a way to rewrite that so the not in and the subselect can be removed?

Comment: Provide the full query. Also the tables' definitions, including indexes.

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`? What indexes do you have?

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN BULK DOWNVOTE...`?

Answer (score 3):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  someClumn
FROM    sometable a
        LEFT JOIN anotherTable b
            ON a.someID = b.anotherID 
               -- AND condition for anotherTable
WHERE   a.something = somethingelse AND
        b.anotherID IS NULL
```

for better performance, define an index on columns: `someID` and `anotherID`.

Comment: I think we have the same answer ... I'll +1 you if you +1 me!

Comment: @svidgen I just can't get the idea of some people doing *massive* downvotes. hehe

Comment: @svidgen And now that I've thrown an answer in I'd like to state for the record that those down-votes appeared long before I saw the question (for now it looks like I was magically left out of the down-voter's wrath). In fact the question was pointed out to me because of the down-votes, and I incorrectly assumed this was a SQL Server question.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select
  distinct somecolumn

from
  sometable t1
  left join anothertable t2 on (t1.someid=t2.otherid and t2.othercondition='else')

where
  t1.something='something else'
  and t2.pk is null
;
```

And t2.otherid should be indexed.

NOTE: The WHERE clause from the subquery is in the JOIN condition.

Comment: wew! `+1`. actually, distinct is already optional since you are searching for non-existent record on the other table so there is no change that the result could be duplicated.

Comment: @JW Good point. I'd +1 you again for omitting it, but alas, I can't.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, `NOT EXISTS` should optimize slightly better than `NOT IN`, and should also be more reliable if `anotherid` is NULLable ([details on this from a SQL Server standpoint](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)). Though I will confess I don't know enough about MySQL to know if this query will be better:

```
SELECT somecolumn 
  FROM dbo.sometable AS s
  WHERE something = somethingelse 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[another table]
    WHERE anotherid = s.someid
  );
```

But I suspect the real performance problem here is lack of indexes, not the presence of a subquery. Is `sometable.something` indexed? How about `sometable.somied`? And `[another table].anotherid`? Also the `DISTINCT` may require an additional sort, but is it truly necessary? If you have duplicates, that might suggest a design problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
select somecolumn
from sometable
     LEFT JOIN another tabele
        ON someid  = anotherid
          AND (where clause from subquery)
WHERE anotherid IS NULL
    AND something = somethingelse
```

I assume DISTINCT redundant if you have One-to-many  relationship.

Comment: Transferring the where clause from the subquery into the main where clause defeats its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select  somecolumn from sometable
      where something = somethingelse and
      someid not in (select anotherid from another tabele where ...)
      GROUP BY somecolumn;
```